# Titan inequality for amateur

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

I have this inequality that I can't solve :

Let $a,b,c>0$ be real numbers such that $abc=1$ then we have :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a^{11}+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b^{11}+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c^{11}+1}})\leq\frac{\sqrt{a}}{(\sqrt{a})^{11}+1}+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{(\sqrt{b})^{11}+1}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{(\sqrt{c})^{11}+1}$$

My try :

I have tried to use a exponential version of Karamata's inequality wich is the following :

Let $a\geq b \ge c>0$ and $e\geq d \ge f>0$ such that :

$a\ge e $ and $ab\ge ed$ and $abc\ge edf$ then :
$$a+b+c\ge e+d+f$$

With that we get :

$$((\sqrt{a})^{11}+1)((\sqrt{b})^{11}+1)((\sqrt{c})^{11}+1)\le(a^{11}+1)(b^{11}+1)(c^{11}+1)$$

Wich is true under the conditions.

But I have some problem with this :

$$\frac{a}{a^{11}+1}\leq \frac{\sqrt{a}}{(\sqrt{a})^{11}+1}$$

And the medium inequality $ab\ge ed$

So can someone achieve my ideas or have nice ideas to prove this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Plotting both expressions for $(a, b, c) = (x, x, 1/x^2)$ as a function of $x$ reveals  that inequality is *wrong* for $a=b=0.85$ and $c=1/0.85^2$

Comment: @MartinR . No wonder its so hard.LOL

Comment: What made you think this inequality held? Is there a typo, or some modification you could make that makes it true?

Comment: See my edits IT Works halleluia !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality holds for all $a,b,c>0$ (we don’t need $abc=1$), as through CS,
$$(a^{11}+1)(1+1)\geqslant ((\sqrt a)^{11}+1)^2$$
$$\implies \frac{\sqrt a}{(\sqrt a)^{11}+1} \geqslant \frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a^{11}+1}}$$
It remains to add similar terms for $b, c,..$